# A grid with dragging/dropping and sorting categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, user-stories

I am trying to build an application that allows users to perform story mapping. A little note to what that is: You have a bunch of sticky notes and you make a map of all user tasks and goals put it across a board.

I have to set up something that allows that. Preferably an independent grid that can place elements and sorts them and allows me to change the size of the grid as well.

What I have done so far:

I utilized the jQuery UI libraries of draggable and sortable. I can sort lists, connect lists, dynamically render a view from the database. Everything is pretty much functional.

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adnanchang/h1aqmkj9/) to the JSFiddle

HTML

```
<!-- <div style="margin: 30px;"> -->
<div class="container" style="display: table;">
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row; ">
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: orange;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: orange;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: orange;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: orange;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: pink;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: pink;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-header" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky" style="background-color: pink;">
        <b>Card Header</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row" style="display: table-row;">
    <div class="sort-me-alpha" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card 1</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card 2</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-beta" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card n</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-me-gamma" style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card 3</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card 4</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
      <div class="sticky">
        <b>Card 5</b> Put any text in here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

$('.sort-me-alpha').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sort-me-gamma, .sort-me-beta, .sort-me-header',
  placeholder: "testclass",
  forcePlaceholderSize: true
});

$('.sort-me-beta').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sort-me-gamma, .sort-me-alpha, .sort-me-header',
  placeholder: "testclass",
  forcePlaceholderSize: true
});

$('.sort-me-gamma').sortable({
  placeholder: "testclass",
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  connectWith: '.sort-me-alpha, .sort-me-beta, .sort-me-header'
});

$('.sort-me-header').sortable({
  placeholder: "testclass",
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  connectWith: '.sort-me-alpha, .sort-me-beta, .sort-me-gamma, .sort-me-header',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    var $list = $(this);

    if ($list.children().length > 1) {
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});
});
```

In the example, the first two rows (orange and pink) are my headers. Each card is placed in a separate sortable list. These lists only take one card. I have done this because if you look at the yellow cards, they are connected lists and if I were to move one card from the middle the cards below will come up and take its place automatically. I know this is the built in behavior and I wanna override it. I tried it with another stackoverflow user and got successful by presenting an empty card that takes place. But that's not rather elegant for the long run of what I want to achieve. Another limitation is that I can't sort the top two rows. They can only accept a card and a card can only leave that placeholder. So in a way to force a certain behavior I am compromising another.

Can anyone guide me here **OR** better yet forward me to an API/Library that better suits my needs and caters to my requirements?